# Real time flot chart with 'stable' x-axis?

Tags: jquery, json, charts, real-time, flot

I want to make a realtime Flot chart which is going to take JSON data from database.

I have created all the files and fortunately i can make a chart with JSON data but the problem is that the chart does not have the “flow” that i want.

The x axis is not stable. What that really means is that my array does not shift the data but it only gets longer and longer with more json data.

Here is an example of what i want -> http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html

and what i’ve made -> http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html (press ‘Poll for data’).

So, what my program does is :

```
[0,44],[1,45],[2,42]…,[n,87]  ==> 
[0,44],[1,45],[2,42]…,[n-1,87],[n,92]

(if x axis = 100 then will go 101)
```

And i think what i should do is :

```
[0,44],[1,45],[2,42]…,[n,87]  ==> 
[1,45],[2,42],[3,48]…,[n-1,87],[n,92]

(if x axis =100 it will stay 100)
```

Any kind of solution/advice will be great!

Thanks in advance!

(the code below is a try to find a solution..)

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var jsonDynamicData;
            var id = 9;
            var totalPoints = 10;
            getRandomData();
            function getRandomData() {
                var result = [];
                $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
                $.post('get_data_test.php', {id:id}, 
                    function(r){
                        jsonDynamicData = jQuery.parseJSON(r);
                        //console.log(jsonDynamicData);                 

                        if (jsonDynamicData.length > 0 ){
                            jsonDynamicData = jsonDynamicData.slice(1);
                        }

                        while(jsonDynamicData.length < totalPoints)
                        {
                            var prev = jsonDynamicData.length > 0 ? jsonDynamicData[jsonDynamicData.length - 1] : 100,
                                y = jsonDynamicData[jasonDynamicData.length];
                               // I'm pretty sure that y value is wrong...
                            jsonDynamicData.push(y);
                        };
                        // Zip the generated y values with the x values
                        for (var i = 0; i < jsonDynamicData.length; ++i) {
                            result.push([i, jsonDynamicData[i]])
                        }
                });
                return result;
            }

                // Set up the control widget
                var updateInterval = 2000;
                $("#updateInterval").val(updateInterval).change(function () {
                    var v = $(this).val();
                    if (v && !isNaN(+v)) {
                        updateInterval = +v;
                        if (updateInterval < 1) {
                            updateInterval = 1;
                        } else if (updateInterval > 2000) {
                            updateInterval = 2000;
                        }
                        $(this).val("" + updateInterval);
                    }
                });
                var options = {
                    series: {
                        shadowSize: 0   // Drawing is faster without shadows
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        show: true
                    }
                };
                var plot = $.plot("#placeholder1", [ getRandomData() ], options);

                function update() {
                    plot.setData([getRandomData()]);
                // Since the axes don't change, we don't need to call plot.setupGrid()
                    plot.draw();
                    setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
                }
                update();

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use shift() instead of slice(1).